# Inserting document into only client side of collection

Tags: collections, meteor

Hey everyone I'm pretty new to meteor and had a question regarding collection workflow.

Is it possible to insert documents only into the client side of a collection, then later fully insert them into the server side of the collection?

Currently I have:

Server side Collection(eg. Posts) -> Publish -> Subscribe -> Client side Collection(Posts) -> Copy to Client only Collection(eg. tempCol) -> Modify Client only Collection(tepmCol) -> Submit and insert into Server Collection (Posts)

What I am trying to do is get rid of the client only collection(tempCol) to something like:

Server side Collection(Posts) -> Publish -> Subscribe -> Client side Collection(Posts) -> Modify data in Client side Collection(Posts) -> Submit and save changes into Server Collection(Posts)

Can I accomplish this through allow/deny rules, then when submitting use a method?

Thank you for the time,
LL

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what you're trying to do, but you can create a client only collection with `clientCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);` to store your client data. Later you can use a Method to store this data in the server.

Comment: I think you're actually following the correct pattern. Using allow/deny rules to deny an update would cause it to be lost completely, you wouldn't be able to defer it to later.  I don't know of any way to defer synchronization of collections.

Comment: I don't see exactly why you would do that. Have you considered session variables to store documents and then later store them in the DB?

Comment: I'm using client only collections because I want the temporary storage of a session variable, but I also want the functionality of a collection (IDs) so I can perform linking between parent/child data that I have.

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
CollectionName._collection.insert({ });

CollectionName._collection.update({ }, { });

CollectionName._collection.remove({ });
```

Comment: Came across this almost 2 years later and it appears that using `_collection` indeed does the trick.